# How to untar `.tgz` directory, and gzip one of the extracted files in memory?

Tags: linux, filesystems

**TL;DR**
How can I untar a file `.tgz`, and then selectively gzip the output?
My extracted dir has a few text files and a `.nii` file. I'd like to gzip the later.

**More details**
First method would be to just do sequentially. However I'm dealing with a huge dataset (10k+ tar archives) stored on a BeeGFS file system and I was told it would be better to do it in memory instead in two steps, since BeeGFS doesn't like handling big directories like this.

Sequential method:

```sh
for tarfile in ${rootdir}/*.tgz; do
  tarpath="${tarfile%.tgz}"
  tar zxvf ${tarfile}       # (1) untar directory
  gzip ${tarpath}/*.nii     # (2) gzip the .nii file
done
```

Is there a way to combine (1) and (2)? Or do you have any other tips on how to do this process effectively?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract a single file from the archive (If you know the filename), and have tar write it to standard output instead of to a file with `-O`, and then compress that stream and redirect *it* to a file. Something like

```
tar xzOf "$tarfile" "$tarpath/foo.nii" | gzip -c > "$tarpath/foo.nii.gz"
```

You can then extract everything else in the archive with `tar xzf "$tarfile" --exclude "*.nii"`

Comment: (All this assumes you're using GNU tar, as the linux tag suggests is likely)